# Sentences with no object

Tags: grammar

I have known for years that sentences do not have to contain the objects. But there are some problems I am facing with great difficulty. For example, sentences below make perfect sense.

> I missed by a big margin.
>
> I played with passion.
>
> I wrote like a real writer.
>
> I sat.

But some of these sentences without objects do not make sense AT ALL.

> I got.
>
> I made.
>
> I show.

Not only do these sentences sound like cavemen, those sentences do not seem to be grammatically correct. Why is that?

Comment: Transitive verbs have objects. Intransitive verbs do not. Ditransitive verbs have a direct and indirect object. Some verbs can take any one of these roles, depending on context.

Comment: So it just depends on the type of the verb?

Comment: @noobject - Yes.  When you look up the verb in the dictionary, notice whether it says "v.t." (transitive) or "v.i." (intransitive).

Answer (score 1):

It's not that the last three don't make sense at all; it's that they are incomplete for most instances because all three verbs have transitive uses.  But an object is not necessary to complete the sense for "got":

> I **got** into the car.

And I can contrive a sense for "show."  For this you have to know that "far along" refers to the time that a woman has been pregnant, and "show" means that it's evident that she's pregnant:

> Q: I hear you're pregnant.  Congratulations.  How far along are you?
>   A: Well, I **show**.

Answer (score 0):

Some verbs in the dictionary are followed by 'v.i' or 'v.t' or even both. Here's some examples... 
 **like**   *(v) v.t.*  I like birds. 
 **think**   *(v) v.i*  I think. 
 **play**   *v.t & v.i*  I played her. / I played.